# Get the text from an editable jQueryUI ComboBox widget even if the text was not one of the options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using an editable Autocomplete combo box from jQueryUI. Specifically, this one: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

If the user selects an existing option, or types the name of an existing option in the combo box, I can get the selected text and value like this:

```
var categoryCombo = $(row).find('.categoryComboBox');
    var selectedOption = $(categoryCombo).find('option:selected');

    var categoryName = ''; var categoryId = 0;

    if (selectedOption.length > 0) {
        categoryId = selectedOption.val();
        categoryName = selectedOption.text();
    }
```

And that works fine.

However, if the user enters text that was not one of the options in the combo box, I would like to retrieve that text as well.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the typed text to the select dropdown dynamically and keep updating the last option value
**JS** -

```
// Add an option and a class to it which would set its visibility to hidden
$('<option class="jsHdnOption hide"></option>').appendTo('.categoryComboBox');
// Find appropriate event which would work for your case
$('.categoryComboBox').on('textchanged',function(){
   var typedText = $('.categoryComboBox').text();
   var hdnOption = $('.jsHdnOption');
   if(typedText!=null && $.trim(typedText)!=''){
      hdnOption.val(typedText);
      hdnOption.removeClass('hide');
   }else{
      hdnOption.addClass('hide');
      hdnOption.val('');
   } 
});
```

**CSS** :

```
.hide { 
visibility : hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thing is, your solution relies on the value of the typed text being available in `$(.categoryComboBox').text()`, which happens not to be the case.

Comment: hmm ... got your point ... you'll need to find the text control created by the jqueryUI plugin I guess ... can do that using `$(".categoryComboBox").parents().find("input:text")` and use that selector instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was just suggesting a better approach in my previous answer (i.e. using a knockout like framework..)

Anyway, in this case you can get the value in the following way:

**$('Selector for the raw combo box').parents('.ui-widget').find('.ui-autocomplete-input').val();**

Jquery UI modifies the dom to add a input field of type text which has the value that is being typed by the user.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Sudipto